# Rewrite slug of custom post type to include post-id

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

My current permalink setting is `/%postname%/%post_id%/`. Would like to use the same with CPT. Currently the URL looks as site.com/questions/title/

Would like to get post id at the end of the url on every single cpt post, similar to that of post type post...

The closest function i found is... (which outputs site.com/questions/postid/)

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'change_post_type_link', 1, 3);

function change_post_type_link( $link, $post = 0 ){
    if ( $post->post_type == 'questions' ){
        return home_url( 'questions/' . $post->ID );
    } else {
        return $link;
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'change_rewrites_init' );

function change_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'questions/([0-9]+)?$',
        'index.php?post_type=questions&p=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
function change_post_type_link( $link, $post = 0 ){
    if ( $post->post_type == 'questions' ){
        return home_url( 'questions/'. $post->post_name .'/'. $post->ID );
    } else {
        return $link;
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'change_rewrites_init' );

function change_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'questions/([a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)?$',
        'index.php?post_type=questions&p=$matches[1]&postid=$matches[2]',
        'top' );
}
```

Here post slug is attached after `questions` in the URL. For example `questions/q-slug/45`. Rewrite rule is changed accordingly.